# Angular Don't Send Content-Type Request Header

Tags: angular

I have to consume an API through CORS in my Angular5 app, but this particular api isn't allowing the Content-Type header in the CORS configuration.  My angular app is currently sending this header, and the preflight check is failing due to the fact that I'm sending a header that isn't explicitly allowed by the API's CORS configuration.  Is there a way to remove this header for this particular request?

I was thinking along the lines of creating an interceptor but is that the most appropriate place to remove this header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution here was to not use Angular's HttpClient and use the fetch api instead.  I couldn't figure out a way to use HttpClient and remove the 'Content-Type' header, even when I wrote an interceptor and explicitly removed this header it was added back somewhere.

Here is what I ended up doing:

```
    return fetch( environment.splunk_config.url, {
        body: JSON.stringify(_message),
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: { 'Authorization': auth }
      }
    )
    .then(response => response.json());
  }
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for this answer. I had the same problem using Splunk Http Event Collector and Angular 6. Use the fetch approach and it worked perfectly. Will file a bug / enhancement request with Splunk dev team

Comment: I'm not sure that this is an issue with Splunk (yes they probably should support the Content-Type header in CORS requests) but I think this is probably a bug with the angular httpclient, I'm not sure why httpclient doesn't allow people to remove the content-type request header.